# Please elaborate the following script(5,7 lines)

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash    
# Declare array  
declare -a ARRAY  
# Link filedescriptor 10 with stdin  
exec 10<&0   
# stdin replaced with a file supplied as a first argument   
exec < $1   
let count=0    

while read LINE; do     
    ARRAY[$count]=$LINE  
    ((count++))  
done  

echo Number of elements: ${#ARRAY[@]}  
# echo array's content   
echo ${ARRAY[@]}   
# restore stdin from filedescriptor 10   
# and close filedescriptor 10   
exec 0<&10 10<&-
```

What do lines 5 (`exec 10<&0`) and 7 (`exec < $1`) do?

Comment: - `while IFS= read -r LINE` will allow to avoid backslashes and space substitution

Comment: - `((count++))` if you do not use `$count` somewhere else the `ARRAY[${#ARRAY[*]}]="$LINE"` is enough to set array element.

Comment: - `exec < $1` what the purpose of play with descriptors? In most cases `while read; do ... ; done < "$1"` is quite usable.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments on line 4 and 6 say it all. The standard input is (arbitrarily) assigned to file descriptor 10, then the content of the file which' name was given as the first argument is assigned to stdin.

At the end of the file this is undone.

It might be that the developer of the script thought that this would prevent invocation of the following form:

```
 echo -e '5\n6' | yourscript
```

(without argument) would prevent the script from reading from stdin, but it doesn't (i.e. output is:

```
yourscript: line 7: $1: ambiguous redirect
Number of elements: 2
5 6
```